# Apply mask to an image in Photoshop script

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I need to create a Photoshop script (I'm using Java Script) that takes a few images and applies the same mask to all of them.

([Here is what I mean by applying a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978958/masking-an-image))

Once I've loaded the images using this code

```
var sourceImageDoc = app.open(new File("./image.png"))
var maskImageDoc = app.open(new File("./mask.png"))
```

how I can set *maskImageDoc* to be the mask for *sourceImageDoc*?

Comment: Do you desperately need to pay for and use Photoshop? If not, you can use ImageMagick which is free and available for Linux, Windows and OSX like this: `convert image.jpg mask.png -compose copy-opacity -composite out.png` It is installed anyway on most Linux distros, and if you are fortunate enough to be on Mac OS X, you can use `homebrew` to install ImageMagick easily enough.

Comment: @MarkSetchell what if he is trying to make a plugin?

Comment: I want to accomplish this task with Photoshop script because I have already implemented significant part of the script. Masking is only one step from a bunch of changes I apply to the set of images

Comment: @Dinal24 Mine was only a suggestion and OP is obviously welcome to use any method he likes. As the question provides little context it is hard to provide a complete answer and that's exactly why I only left a comment. If a better statement of the question appears it may be possible to solve the entire problem with a couple of lines of ImageMagick.

Comment: Is your mask image a solid shape?  If so you can create a selection from the mask image and then apply it to the image by automating the create mask from selection commands.

Comment: @AnnaForrest The mask is quite simple, it's basically an oval, and I tried to apply mask from simple selection (I used selection.selectAll() just for testing), and even in this trivial case I couldn't make it to even execute without errors. If you can come up with a sample code how to select a circle shape and set it to mask the layer, I'll accept it as an answer

Comment: do you want a clipping mask or a layer mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some snippets out of one of my scripts that works CS3 +.  As you can see it uses the ugly script listener code - if you're applying it to a layer rather than a group, you may need to adjust that part?  I'm not sure I remember ever using that function on a layer rather than a layerset.

```
//mask group to paper area 
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = lyr;   
selectRasterLayerContents();
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = grp;
AddMaskToGroup();   


//Selects the contents of the active layer.
function selectRasterLayerContents() {
var id47 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id48 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref11 = new ActionReference();
        var id49 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var id50 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
        ref11.putProperty( id49, id50 );
    desc11.putReference( id48, ref11 );
    var id51 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
        var ref12 = new ActionReference();
        var id52 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var id53 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var id54 = charIDToTypeID( "Trsp" );
        ref12.putEnumerated( id52, id53, id54 );
    desc11.putReference( id51, ref12 );
executeAction( id47, desc11, DialogModes.NO );
}


//adds a mask revealing the selection to the active group
function AddMaskToGroup() {
    var id42 = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
    var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id43 = charIDToTypeID( "Nw  " );
    var id44 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    desc8.putClass( id43, id44 );
    var id45 = charIDToTypeID( "At  " );
        var ref10 = new ActionReference();
        var id46 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var id47 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var id48 = charIDToTypeID( "Msk " );
        ref10.putEnumerated( id46, id47, id48 );
    desc8.putReference( id45, ref10 );
    var id49 = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
    var id50 = charIDToTypeID( "UsrM" );
    var id51 = charIDToTypeID( "RvlS" );
    desc8.putEnumerated( id49, id50, id51 );
executeAction( id42, desc8, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying a layer mask is a pain, because script listener won't hear it directly.

You'll want this then

```
function applyLayerMask()
{

var id1949 = charIDToTypeID( "Dlt " );
var desc398 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id1950 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref291 = new ActionReference();
var id1951 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
var id1952 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
var id1953 = charIDToTypeID( "Msk " );
ref291.putEnumerated( id1951, id1952, id1953 );
desc398.putReference( id1950, ref291 );
var id1954 = charIDToTypeID( "Aply" );
desc398.putBoolean( id1954, true );
executeAction( id1949, desc398, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: My goal is to apply a mask using script, I don't care how exactly to do this, using selections or another technics available in Photoshop. What is the idea of your answer? Your code only changes active document and doesn't do anything else

Comment: I've changed my answer, I thought you were having trouble swapping focus from one image to another. You might want to [look here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842581/photoshop-js-script-to-create-and-apply-a-layer-mask)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to apply a layer mask to the currently selected object (provided it has a selection).

```js
const layerMask = function () {
    const makeID = stringIDToTypeID('make')
    const newID = stringIDToTypeID('new')
    const channelID = stringIDToTypeID('channel')
    const atID = stringIDToTypeID('at')
    const usingID = stringIDToTypeID('using')
    const userMaskEnabledID = stringIDToTypeID('userMaskEnabled')
    const revealSelectionID = stringIDToTypeID('revealSelection')

    const actionDesc = new ActionDescriptor()
    const actionRef = new ActionReference()

    actionDesc.putClass(newID, channelID)
    actionRef.putEnumerated(channelID, channelID, maskID)
    actionDesc.putReference(atID, actionRef)
    actionDesc.putEnumerated(usingID, userMaskEnabledID, revealSelectionID)

    executeAction(makeID, actionDesc, DialogModes.NO)
}
```

Tested in Photoshop CC 2021

Comment: actionRef.putEnumerated(channelID, channelID, maskID) needs maskID which is not defined anywhere. Is that a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here's my simple method for adding a mask to a layer in ExtendScript. The trick here is to place a copy of the mask just below the image, then merge the image into it. Note that the merge will destroy the original layer object and create a new one, so I always assign the result back to my original variable; otherwise it will become undefined.

```
// imageLayer: an artLayer in imageDoc that I want to mask
// maskLayer:  an artLayer in maskDoc w/ just the mask to be added, no image data
// if both are in same file, you may not need the activeDocument assignments

app.activeDocument = maskDoc;
maskLayer.duplicate(imageLayer,ElementPlacement.PLACEAFTER);
app.activeDocument = imageDoc;
imageLayer = imageLayer.merge();
```

Now, this just *adds* the mask to the image layer non-destructively (i.e., it can be removed layer if you like). If you want to truly *apply* the mask (permanently conform the image to the mask while deleting the mask), then just duplicate a completely blank layer (no mask) below the masked merge-result from the first step above, and then merge that masked result one more time down into the blank layer.